# I can't use LocalDateTime

Tags: java, intellij-idea2017

Both of them don't work. I wrote the errors after "—"

```
LocalDateTime date = new LocalDateTime.now(); // cannot resolve symbol 'now' 
LocalDateTime date = new LocalDateTime(); // LocalDateTime has private access
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message `LocalDateTime has private access` indicates that the compiler has imported `LocalDateTime` successfully.

First, validate that you're using the `LocalDateTime` we expect. Look at the imports. You should see:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
```

Now read the [Javadoc for this class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

`new LocalDateTime()` is trying to invoke a zero-argument constructor. The Javadoc does not list any constructors, because there are none that are not private.

`new LocalDateTime.now()` is trying to invoke the zero-argument constructor of a class called `LocalDateTime.now`. There is no class with that name, which is why you get the error `cannot resolve symbol 'now'`

What you actually want to do is to call the static method `now()` of the `LocalDateTime` class. To do that you **do not use `new`**.

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Try creating your own class with static factory methods, and remind yourself how to call its methods.

```
public class MyThing {

     private MyThing() { // private constructor
     };

     public static MyThing thing() {
         return new MyThing();
     }
}
```

You'll find that you get the same errors if you try to use this from another class with `new MyThing()` or `new MyThing.thing()`. `MyThing.thing()` will work.

Answer (score 1):

now() is a static method. Try this:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off, assuming you're using Java 8+, without an `import` it might look like,

```
java.time.LocalDateTime date = java.time.LocalDateTime.now();
```

and if you have `import java.time.LocalDateTime;` then you only need

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
```

to invoke the `static` [`LocalDateTime#now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--) (note there are multiple `now()` functions provided, this makes it much easier to effectively use different time zones).

Comment: I already imported, but LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now() doesn't work. "Java:cannot find symbol"

Comment: @Kadzii Then you must be setup to target a version of Java earlier than 8. Because `LocalDateTime` wasn't added until version 8 of Java.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You probably do have Java 8 already. The compiler error `LocalDateTime has private access` indicates that the class exists and that you've imported it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but in case if anyone have a same issue.

If you get error just for now() section probably the issue is from your minimum SDK.

For using LocalDateTime.now() you must set the **minSdk** to **26**.

Hope it helps.